# Choice of words referring to being attacked/assaulted with a glass/cup

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

According to the Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary the verb, [glass](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glass), means to encase in glass.  Recently, it has also come to mean being [attacked or assaulted by a glass vessel/container](http://www.brisbanetimes.com.au/queensland/another-glassing-incident-woman-19-charged-20091108-i3bd.html) as in this example:

> Another glassing incident... A young woman faces assault charges after allegedly glassing a man in a Brisbane bar early today.

Similar incidents have been reported [with a coffee cup](http://www.chroniclelive.co.uk/north-east-news/evening-chronicle-news/2011/08/09/pensioner-hit-with-coffee-cup-in-consett-pub-72703-29204438/), as in this example:

> bizarre coffee cup attack between two elderly men over a woman. ...It is understood the younger man was hit over the head with a coffee cup in a popular town centre pub and was also scalded by a hot drink on Saturday morning.

Would this still be considered a *glassing incident*, or would it be considered (and I am not trying to be funny here) a *mugging* or *mugging incident*?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glassing) has an article on glassing.  It says that in the UK there is on average one glassing every couple hours.

Answer (score 8):

This meaning of *glass* is not that recent. According to the Oxford English Dictionary:

> trans. slang (orig. and chiefly Brit.). To strike (a person) with a (broken) glass or bottle, esp. in the face.

It was first noted in the 1930s. However, it is a transferred sense of the word--it is likely that the meaning is creating a use like "stoning" out of "glass". Therefore, it is *possible* that "mugging" could gain a similar transferred sense.

However, *mug* already has a fairly accepted usage as a verb where *glass* as a verb does not (at least, not in current usage). Thus, I think it is less likely for *mugging* to gain the same form of transferred meaning.

I don't think *glassing* would apply to the coined *mugging*, as it seems to refer more to a broken bottle. A term you might use in this situation would be that one was "stabbed with a [makeshift weapon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improvised_weapon)". This is clunky, but then one could describe exactly what common item was turned into a weapon.

Comment: There's one part of the question you don't fully address: if *mugging* is not synonymous with *glassing*, what should the OP use to describe glassing incidents that don't involve a glass, like the one with the coffee mug? (Are they still glassing incidents?)

Answer (score 3):

**Glassing**, as in stabbing someone with a broken bottle/glass, was given its own word because of how common it was.
Doing the same with a mug is hardly commonplace. As such, I'd recommend the more generic **shanking** which refers to the act of stabbing someone with a homemade or improvised weapon (as is commonplace in prison).

Comment: That's a fair point regarding the word [shanking](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shank), however, as I wouldn't expect to be penetrated by a coffee mug as I would a glass vessel/container, or a makeshift weapon for that matter, I was thinking along the lines of an act/offense that would cause [blunt trauma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blunt_trauma).